# Python: Convert specific value in dictionary from string to int

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to convert specific value in dictionary from string to int.

**This is the dictionary:**

```
 for r in repo_tags:
            name, tag = r.split(":")
            image = {"repo": name, "tag": tag, "id": img_id[1][:12], "full_name": r}
            print(image["repo"])
            images.append(image)
            print(image)
```

**This is the output:**

```
{'repo': 'python', 'tag': 'latest', 'id': '254d4a8a8f31', 'full_name': 'python:latest'}
nginx
{'repo': 'nginx', 'tag': 'latest', 'id': '35c43ace9216', 'full_name': 'nginx:latest'}
hello-world
{'repo': 'hello-world', 'tag': 'latest', 'id': 'bf756fb1ae65', 'full_name': 'hello-world:latest'}
```

The id is a string, but i want this to be an int to make it a primary key in database.

Is this possible to change only this value to an int?

Comment: How would you convert it? I am guessing hex, but no way to know based on your question

Comment: `"id": img_id[1][:12]` -> `"id": int(img_id[1][:12], 16)` second argument in `int` is base, so this will convert it from hex string to int